# Bandwidth for C# IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, oauth, identityserver4

I've inherited a legacy application that utilizes a C# implementation of IdentityServer4 to handle its OAuth work.

Recently we've started to see a lot of degradation in performance, with no changes made, and sometimes full failure of the AWS server that the OAuth app runs on.

The only change is that we are getting significantly more traffic in the app now.

Looking at the logs, I'm seeing the client app hitting the introspection endpoint per user every second that they are logged in. As far as I could find, the intention behind the introspection endpoint is to check the token status. It seems very wrong that this would be hit every single second, is this a common practice?

I'm just looking for some clarity on a traditional use case.

Comment: There may be hardware issues like a bad cable or router.  To verify hardware I usually recommend using ping and sending large amount of data :  ping -t -l 65500 IP

Comment: Your (usually) APIs that client apps talk to can be configured to cache the introspection responses, and usually are for some reasonable period that fits your business needs. An hour would not be unusual. If you control or know who controls the APIs you can get them to turn this on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was the status of the logging on the OAuth server. It turned out that the previous owner had turned on verbose logging and memory was filling on the OAuth server purely from the log file output.

We solved it by reducing the logging to pure errors only.